# how to access value within json dictionary and list

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am facing a small problem. I had to add data from my search-engine to web page. Can someone guide me how can I access data from a list which is inside a dictionary. e .g

I write the following code to display results in console and web page.

```
data = JSON.parse(result);

for (var item in data['data']['hits']['hits']) {
    console.log(data);
    $('.class name').each(function(){ 
        $(this).append(data);
    });
}
```

I had to access name and user name. I write the above code but it only display the object on web page where as in console I can access the name and user_name from object but in web page I don't know how to do this .

JSON format is like this

```
{
    "data": {
      "hits": {
        "hits": [{
            "_score": 1.8235999,
            "_type": "xray",
            "_id": "1234",
            "_source": {
              "user_name": "kamil",
              "name": "ahmed"
            },
            "_index": "mri",
            .....
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

My question is how can I access the `name` and `user_name` from this JSON format so that I append them to web page.

Comment: The json format was wrong.

Comment: Is your JSON structure dynamic?

Comment: the format is not wrong. actually I am getting those results from elastic search and I display them in console. But I want to display name and user name and in console it look like this. ..................data: Object
                     _shards: Object
                                      hits: Object
                                           hits: Array[1]
  0: Object
    _id: "1234"
    _index: "mri"

   _source: Object
    name : "ahmed"
    user_name: "kamil".        I want to access name and user_name only  from this

Comment: Voting down for comment `the format is not wrong`. The array format inside your json was wrong.

Comment: @MamdouhFreelancer yes the structure is dynamic.

Comment: @TânNguyễn the array format is also right. because there are hundred of data and in end the array is closed with  ] and }} . so format is correct . the problem is , how can I access name and user name.

Comment: If I can make double votes. I would vote down for you again. Checking for `{}` and `[]`

Comment: @TânNguyễn I got the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a small example, maybe this helps:

```js
var data = {
  "data": {
    "hits": {
      "hits": [{
        "_score": 1.8235999,
        "_type": "xray",
        "_id": "1234",
        "_source": {
          "user_name": "kamil",
          "name": "ahmed"
        },
        "_index": "mri"
      },{
        "_score": 1.8235999,
        "_type": "xray",
        "_id": "1234",
        "_source": {
          "user_name": "username2",
          "name": "hello"
        },
        "_index": "mri"
      },{
        "_score": 1.8235999,
        "_type": "xray",
        "_id": "1234",
        "_source": {
          "user_name": "username 3",
          "name": "asdf"
        },
        "_index": "mri"
      }]
    }
  }
};

for (var hit in data.data.hits.hits) {
  var hit = data.data.hits.hits[hit];
  var source = hit._source;
  var index  = hit._index;
  var id     = hit._id;
  $('div').append(source.user_name + ' - ' + source.name + '<br/>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: one small thing. How can I access_id and _index from above example. thanx for guiding

Comment: @kamilahmed same as you access _source. I updated my example with index and id vars.

Comment: Thank you very much. you really save my day. it works perfectly.

Comment: I need one last suggestion and then I hope I am done with this task. I had 600 results and the page shows only first 30 search results. I had to apply pagination. Should I ask this question separately? because I spend 3 days on pagination, but I got no clear direction. I had to apply pagination on the same results and code.

Comment: @kamilahmed yes, this should be a new question.

Comment: I log after a long time and saw that i didn't accept this answer cox it work well at that time, cox i was new at stack overflow at that time. .sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something as this for one hit:

```
data = JSON.parse(result);

var hit = data['data']['hits']['hits'][0];
if(hit){
    var source = hit["_source"];
    if(source){
        var user_name = source["user_name"];
        var name = source["name"]; 
    }
}
```

Based on this you could apply to the whole array.

```
function getSourceProps(source) {
    if(source){
        return {
            usernname: source["user_name"],
            name: source["name"]
        };
    }
    return {};
}

data = JSON.parse(result);

var hits = data['data']['hits']['hits'];
// You could simply use a for. The for...in structure is used for other purposes.
for (var i=0; i<hits.length; i++) {
    // I can't understand why you make this selection. So I left it.
    $('.class name').each(function(){ 
        var props = getSourceProps(hits["source"]);
        if(props.length){
           $(this).append(props.username+" "+props.name);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Voting down for unknown selector `$('.class name')`. Html has no `<name/>` tag

Comment: @TânNguyễn He has a comment "I can't understand why you make this selection. So I left it"

Comment: @TânNguyễn it's part of post. It's not an error. Obviously no one would put `class` as a value to class attribute.

Comment: So, I would give another reason: `data['data']['hits']['hits'][0]` is **NOT** an array. Your code couldn't be compiled.

Comment: @TânNguyễn do you have the exact json? The OP states it's like this. All my reasoning is based on the OP post. I can't assume anything more or less that this.  Apparently, there are many things that don't make sense to me, but I have to confine my skeptical on OP post. Furthermore, If you notice the `hits` contained in the `hits` (one of the weird things I just mentioned), has a value something that starts with brackets. If I am not wrong this is one of the ways we define arrays in JavaScript - the most common way. Is this wrong?

Comment: @TânNguyễn Apparently, that OP has in hist post is not a proper json. I have no disagreement on this. If you read my comment, I stated that OP has written in hist post, *it's like this*. If you judge my answer based on the fact that the OP posted a something like this, I have no problem, just let me know. But please don't make any arguments on the fact that this is a json, because it's isn't and I have never stated that.

Comment: First. I've commented that `The json format was wrong`. Then, he/she said `the format is not wrong`. I've voted down and tell he/she where the incorrect point. He/she still said it's true. Everything was true but an error after compiling?

Comment: I am sorry but I can't get your point. This is why I will not delete my answer. However, I appreciate that you try to reason about your downvote. Unfortunately it is not a common behaviour in our community. Best regards.

Comment: @TânNguyễn I mention that I got your point and I accept my mistake. I was just trying to tell that this is what I got in my console. I was not reasoning with you nor I was disrespectful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You're appending `data` which is the root object, instead append `item`.

For example

```
data = JSON.parse(result);
var list = data['data']['hits']['hits'];
for (var item in list) {
    console.log(data);
    $('.class name').each(function(){ 
        $(this).append(item['_score']);//or any other property in the object inside list
    });
}
```